# Jumps screen when entering text on Android

Tags: android, html, layout

Welcome. Developing a mobile version of the site, and when testing revealed the problem. When I enter text in the input - jumps screen, sharply down - then up, and far beyond the visibility of an element which enters text.

On the iPhone does not have this problem.
How can I fix it?

OS: Android
Browser: Chrome

Comment: Have you tried something? Could you show us the code involved? We can't answer the question based on what you are saying

Comment: Are you using any transformations or transitions on this mobile version?

Comment: I added link to site

Comment: Well, it's working fine for me. I'm using a nexus 5 with 4.4.4